# DataStructure<> data = new DataStructure<>(__ What does this part do?, What can go in here? __)

Tags: java

I've seen data structures being declared with multiple things in the right side of the expression in the brackets. I've seen other data structures and lambda functions put in there but I'm just genuinely curious what happens inside the brackets and what's designated to go there. In the case of a lambda function, how does it apply to the DS?

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(___RIGHT HERE___)
```

Comment: They're just arguments to the constructor, what they do depends on the details of the thing you're using. For an ArrayList you can pass an initial capacity, for example.

Comment: Just look [at the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a parameter given to the constructor, the simple example is when you do `B b = new B(1);`

```
class B {
    int a;

    B(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

---

For `ArrayList` the [`third constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) accepts a collection of data to get initial data

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>(anotherList);
```

---

If you pass a lambda, it's that the constructor accepts something that matches, a supplier, a consumer, other, like :

```
//  Use
A a = new A(() -> 5);
System.out.println(a.run());

class A {
    Supplier<Integer> fct;

    A(Supplier<Integer> f) {
        fct = f;
    }

    Integer run() {
        return fct.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe commented on your question, it depends on the class and its declared constructor.

In most cases, you can put there another `Collection` and the new data structure will copy the elements inside it. But don't take this for granted. As @VLAZ commented on your question, always check the documentation.